# Sum the contents of divs when their corresponding checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in a loop reading the contents of a folder:

```
<div class="oddrow">
    <span class="title">1 - 1215 - Magna Carta</span><br/>
    <span class="size">size: 229.1 MB</span>
    <input name="1215 - Magna Carta" type="checkbox">
<div>
```

When the checkbox gets checked I want to have the sizes of each record added up in a separate div:

```
<div id="total>total = </div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it correct that you only want to add the ones that have a checked checkbox? -- Also, do you have JQuery?

Comment: @jsalvy This question is tagged jquery, so...

Comment: @jsalvy - yep, only the ones which are checked, and also yeah I have jquery installed

Comment: You may want to add the size without any text into an hidden span...
<span class="size">size: 229.1 MB <span class="_size" style="display:none;">229.1</span></span>
It will be much easier to calculate

Comment: It's not very difficult to do, the more tricky part could be the conversion of units... are all numbers representing MBs?

Comment: I can get all thosenumbers as kb values no probs, so that's not a problem :)

Comment: Which unit it is does not matter, I wanted to know if every entry uses the same unit or if you will have MBs, GBs, KBs mixed in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shane said, it would be better to save the plain number in an attribute. If that's not a possibility you could still do it like that:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).prev().text().match(/[\d\.]+/));
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bGjP4/

Here's how you could save it as value in the checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I can save it as an attribute ok, is it better to have it as a value=""? I can do either

Comment: @crazysarah it's really up to you. you can either save it inside the span as a `data-size` attr or in the checkbox as value. which would be cleaner and easier in my opinion. i updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted eventually!

Answer (score 3):

If you can adjust the HTML, I would suggest putting the size value in a data attribute of the size span or the checkbox.  This would make your jquery total calculation much easier...

```
<input name="..." type="checkbox" data-size="229.1" class="checkTotal" />
```

Then your jquery would be something like :

```
$(function() {

    var total = 0;
    $(".checkTotal:checked").each(function(idx, elem) {
         total = total + parseFloat($(elem).data('size'));
    });
    $('#total').text('total = ' + total);

});
```

Comment: If not otherwise in use, I would use the `value` attribute.

Comment: @FelixKling : Guess I get so jquery-centric I forget the obvious at times...  ;)

Comment: @ShaneBlake is there something else to make this work? I've put the javascript in a <script> tag in the head of my page but does it need to be in a function?

Comment: @crazy: You can only access DOM element once they have been created. If you execute this script before that, jQuery won't be able to find the elements. Please refer to this part of the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Hello_jQuery

Comment: @crazy:  I've added the two lines you'd need to make sure the elements are there before you try to use them as per Felix's comment...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each( 
            function() { 
               sum += $(this).siblings('.size').text().split(' ')[1];
            } 
        );
        $('#total').text('total = ' + sum);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming since your question is tagged with jQuery, that you are using jQuery.

If you had divs like this (notice the few classes I added):

```
<div class="oddrow rows_to_add">
    <span class="title">1 - 1215 - Magna Carta</span><br/>
    <span class="size">size: <span class="size">229.1</span> MB</span>
    <input name="1215 - Magna Carta" class="add_when_checked" type="checkbox">
<div>
<div class="evenrow rows_to_add">
    <span class="title">1 - 1215 - Magna Carta</span><br/>
    <span class="size">size: <span class="size">229.1</span> MB</span>
    <input name="1215 - Magna Carta" class="add_when_checked" type="checkbox">
<div>
```

And the total div:

```
<div id="total>total = <span id="total"></span></div>
```

The jQuery code to sum them:

```
$( '.add_when_checked' ).change( function() {
   var total = 0;
   $( '.rows_to_add' ).each( function() {
      var $this = $( this );
      if ( $this.find( '.add_when_checked' ).attr( 'checked' ) ) {
         total += $this.find( '.size' ).html();
      }
   } );
   $( '#total' ).html( total );
} );
```

Basically this says, when a checkbox changes state, cycle through all divs with the class "rows_to_add", check when the contained checkbox with the class "add_when_checked" is checked, and if so, add the value within the span with the class "size" to the total. Once you have the total, place it in the div with the id "total".

Another way might be something like this:

```
$( '.add_when_checked' ).change( function() {
   var total = 0;
   $( '.add_when_checked:checked' ).each( function() {
      total += $( this ).parent().find( '.size' ).html();
   } );
   $( '#total' ).html( total );
} );
```

Which uses the selector to find which checkboxes are checked instead of a conditional, then uses parent traversal to find the related size span.

Comment: this is a bit more complicated than simply adding the value to each checkbox in some way, because that allows you to not have any conditionals, and instead use the selector itself to only add values where the checkbox is checked, but this solution illustrates how to check whether a checkbox is checked, then find a related value within a span (the long way).